# Command line arguments for a program run in a makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to specify some command line parameters in a makefile. I normally run my program like
this:

```
 gcc -o prog prog2.c prog.c

 ./prog text1.txt text2.txt
```

Makefile:

```
prog: prog2.o prog.o
    gcc -o prog prog2.o prog.o 


prog2.o: prog2.c prog2.h
    gcc -c prog2.c

clean :
    rm prog2.o
```

How do I include the txt files here?

Also how do I give executions in a single make file. Say if I also want to run

```
  gcc -o prog prog3.c prog.c

  ./prog text1.txt text2.txt
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a `run` target:

```
.PHONY: run
run: prog
    ./prog text1.txt text2.txt

prog: prog2.o prog.o
    gcc -o prog prog2.o prog.o

# etc.
```

Then you can say `make run`, or just `make` if `run` is the first target in the `Makefile`.

Comment: it works. How do i run two programs with the same makefile? say                                                      gcc -o prog prog2.c prog.c                                       ./prog text1.txt text2.txt  along with                                gcc -o prog prog3.c prog.c                                       ./prog text1.txt text2.txt

Comment: Add both programs as dependencies of the `run` target, and add two commands to the recipe of the `run` target.

Comment: sorry sir , but i am unable to understand as i am writing a make file for the first time. could you show it by editing my post? sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

```
test: prog
    ./prog text1.txt text2.txt
```

Or:

```
TEST_FILES = text1.txt text2.txt

test: prog
    ./prog ${TEST_FILES}
```